# Make mutiple single-line strings shortcut Flutter

Tags: flutter, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut, flutter-test, flutter-shortcuts

I'm just wondering if there is any shortcut to making multiple lines into separate strings. I was making a list and copied in data from worldtimeapi.com, in the format:

```
List<list_Of_Places> placeList = ["""
  Africa/Abidjan
  Africa/Accra
  Africa/Algiers
  Africa/Bissau
  Africa/Cairo
  Africa/Casablanca
  Africa/Ceuta
  Africa/El_Aaiun
"""];
```

And now I want to make these into separate strings. I was wondering if there is any shortcut to this or will I have to put '...' on every line? Like this:

```
List<list_Of_Places> placeList = [
  'Africa/Abidjan'
  'Africa/Accra'
  'Africa/Algiers'
  'Africa/Bissau'
  'Africa/Cairo'
  'Africa/Casablanca'
  'Africa/Ceuta'
  'Africa/El_Aaiun'
];
```

Sorry if my formating is bad, this is my first post here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use split on the list String. like this

```dart
List<String> placeList = ["""
  Africa/Abidjan
  Africa/Accra
  Africa/Algiers
  Africa/Bissau
  Africa/Cairo
  Africa/Casablanca
  Africa/Ceuta
  Africa/El_Aaiun
"""];
List seperatedPlaceList = placeList[0].trim().split('\n'); // split by line break
print(seperatedPlaceList);
```

Comment: It needs a `trim()` too.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do it programmatically, you can use your IDE's **Replace-All** functionality with your copied text in a new file to replace each `<new-line>` character with `',<new-line>'` like this..

[image]

which will give you this on replacing-all

[image]

and lastly you can add 2 single quotes manually, one at the start and one at the end.